# Git interactive rebase not allowing changes

Tags: git

I've run into a problem trying to do interactive rebases (e.g. to squash or reorder commits).

On requesting the rebase, my text editor opens as expected, but it begins to run the rebase immediately - i.e. before I've had the chance to actually save any changes to the git-rebase-todo file (hence git thinks it has successfully rebased, but it's impossible to actually make any changes).

Anyone have any idea what might be going on? And how to fix it?

I can't see anything odd in my git config.

Comment: Are you on Windows? How did you configure your editor?

Comment: This sounds like the usual editor-vs-agent issue (which occurs with editors like `atom` that run in their own window(s); `atom foo` signals the editor to open the file, then by default exits; you must add some kind of "wait for the editor to tell me it's done" flag to make the command hang around until the editing is done, so that Git also waits).

Comment: @torek - yes, adding a --wait flag to the editor setting has fixed it. Thanks for that =D. Not sure why the problem started (it had previously worked on this computer, and I don't recall changing the setting since a time when it worked), but it works now so that's good.